# A differential equation of order 2.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+\frac{y'}{x-1}=x(x-1)$$

I use the substitution $u=y'$ and then $y''=uu'$, but then I do not know what to do next.

Comment: This is a first order linear differential equation in $y'$

Comment: So may I write it like it was y''=u'?

Comment: OK. $y''=u'$ and $y'=u$.

Comment: OK. Is there any time I just have to write that $y''=uu'$?

Comment: Yes. when in your equation there is not any $x$, you take $y''=uu'$ and $y'=u$. In this case $y$ will be independent variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''+\frac{y'}{x-1}=x(x-1)$$
Let $y'=u$. Then, $y''=u'$.
$$u'+\frac{1}{x-1}u=x(x-1)$$

This is a linear first order differential equation of the form
$$u'+uP(x)=Q(x)$$
which can be solved by the usual method.